# Firefox 3.6 and 5 won't stop complaining about certificates

Tags: firefox, ssl

I have OS X 10.6, and I was recently using Firefox 3.6, and sites kept on complaining about ssl-certificates. I decided to upgraded to Firefox 5 to see if this would fix the issue, but Firefox keeps complaining about ssl certificates constantly. It complains about calendar.Google.com and many other world-renown sites. I keep adding them to my exception but I truly think something is wrong with my install.

Any advice on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a [new Firefox profile](http://www.blogiversity.org/blogs/willburns1/archive/2008/12/02/how-to-create-mutiple-users-in-firefox-on-a-mac-osx.aspx) and see if that helps.